# How to reload the Tab activity when the tab changes?

Tags: android

how to reload the activity when tab is select again? please give me a example code..when i press the tab it give me old output but i want to reload that activity for new updated output so please help me      Thanks a lot.

Comment: @harding Indenting your question text with 4 spaces causes it to be formatted as code. Edited...

Comment: You could use the Activity Lifecycle. onResume, will be called everytime you switch to your Tab

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just use `.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` to your tab class

**Example**

```
 tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Your Tab")
        .setIndicator("tab indicator")
        .setContent(new Intent(this, TabClass.class)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));
```

Comment: i have different scenario....
how to reload activity when same tab selected,
suppose tabC-->Activity A--> Activity Aa(Same tab)-->now selecte tabC again-->How to reload Activity A ??

Comment: @Tanmay Mandal If we add the flag, the activity will refresh every time I open its tab. Is there any way to refresh it at some particular action?

Answer (score 1):

You can use onWindowFocusChanged method also if you need to do add some more process when getting the focus for a particular tab..

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //You can add your own method to refresh data within the tab                 //(Ex:  refreshData())

super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

}
```